# cannot login via ssh

Tags: ssh, pam

Can not login to SLES server via ssh as `user1`. At the same time I can login as `root` user without any problem. Authentication method is password based. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have `PasswordAuthentication yes`.

`node1:~ # ssh -v -v -v user1@node2` after entering password gives:

```
Password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 17 padlen 15 extra_pad 64)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

The following log entries are present in the authorisation log file,

```
Jul 6 13:44:37 node2 sshd[23303]: pam_listfile(sshd:auth): Refused user user1 for service sshd 
Jul 6 13:44:39 node2 sshd[23294]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for user1 from node1
```

Comment: what is in your server ssh log? There must be a reason for denying authentication.
Wrong password? Pam configuration?

Comment: A few lines before the first prompt would be useful. What we see here is not password authentication but rather keyboard-interactive authentication.

Comment: @Jakuje, Jul  6 13:44:37 node2 sshd[23303]: pam_listfile(sshd:auth): Refused user user1 for service sshd
Jul  6 13:44:39 node2 sshd[23294]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for user1 from node1.
Seems like pam_listfile have some list of barred users

Comment: @kasperd, debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive  debug3: remaining preferred: password  
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive  
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive  
debug2: userauth_kbdint  
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply  
debug2: input_userauth_info_req  
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1  
Password:  
Here they are. Keyboard-interactive indeed

Comment: I found pam config `/etc/pam.d/sshd` which had the following line
`auth     required       pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/sshdusers onerr=succeed`. And in `/etc/sshdusers` my user1 was listed. I deleted user1, restarted sshd and it works.

Comment: @YuraVasylenko glad it's working, when ServerFault allows you, you should come back and enter that as an answer, so it's detailed there rather than just as a comment.

Comment: @EightBitTony There is nothing stopping users from answering their own question immediately. As far as I recall only accepting your own answer and putting a bounty on a question must wait until the question is at least 48 hours old.

Comment: Ah thanks @kasperd - it's a while since I answered one of my own.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in PAM configuration file for sshd daemon `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. The raw within `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
auth  required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/sshdusers onerr=succeed
```

means that `pam_listfile` module will deny `sshd` service for all users listed in `/etc/sshdusers`